# How to change user (not admin) password in PgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have created a new user for my new schema. I want to set its password but I am unable to find how to do it in PgAdmin4. I know how to do it with SQL but I was wondering if such basic functionality is really missing from PgAdmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set somebody else password, connect to the DB, on the left panel select `user/roles`, click on the user of interest, properties, then go on the `definition` tab and enter the new password.

Comment: Note that this sends password in plain form to the server, where it can end up in the log file.  (Unlike when you change your own password from the Object menu, in which case it hashes on the client side before sending).  There seems to be no way to do what he wants responsibly.